# How to integrate django-rest-swagger 2.0 with existing DRF application(Beginner)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am trying to integrate swagger 2.0 with existing DRF application but it gives following error in browser after running`python manage.py runserver`:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /swagger rest_framework_swagger/index.html
>   Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/swagger
>   Django Version:   1.10 Exception Type:    TemplateDoesNotExist Exception
>   Value:     rest_framework_swagger/index.html Exception
>   Location: C:\Users\MHAZIQ~1\Desktop\Tkxel\mmg-git\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py
>   in get_template, line 25

I have added following lines in
views.py:

`from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view`

`schema_view = get_swagger_view(title='Pastebin API')`

And I have added following lines in
urls.py:

`url(r'^swagger', views.schema_view),`

I ve tried applying following solution:
[TemplateDoesNotExist at /docs/ rest_framework_swagger/index.html](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/53)

but it didnot solve my problem, Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several hours of research I have found the problem with my code, as I was adding swagger into an existing project, it didnt have following parameters in settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

Now swagger works absolutely fine!

Answer (score 10):

Add 'rest_framework_swagger' to INSTALLED_APPS in Django settings.

**settings.py**

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
        'rest_framework_swagger',
    ]
```

https://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/